# Conversion of PEM files to JKS files on Mac OS

Tags: java, macos, ssl, pem, jks

I want to convert pem files to jks files as like follows,

**only I have following files:**

```
caroot.pem                                             
key.pem
certificate.pem
```

**I want to get jks files using pem files**

```
 *caroot.pem as keystr.jks
 key.pem    as key
 certificate.pem as trststr.jks*

I want to fetch jks files from pem 

     I have tried several other ways but those didnt work for me.    `
```

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can convert .pem file from jks or vice-versa basically JKS is Java Key Store you need to create a Keystore where you put or import keys.

If you only want to import a certificate in PEM format into a Keystore, keytool will do the job:

```
keytool -import -alias *alias* -keystore cacerts -file *cert.pem*
```

or you ca follow official java oracle doc :
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35976_01/server.740/es_admin/src/tadm_ssl_convert_pem_to_jks.html

I hope this is what you are looking for.